# Can Fiedler vector be used for displaying an undirected graph in a sequential manner?

Tags: graphs, np-complete, user-interface

My problem is to display an undirected unweighted graph in a grid format ( $ (n \times 3) $ - matrix for simplicity) without compromising on the connections displayed on the screen (the only connections that would be displayed are between adjacent nodes in the grid).

One way I could think of is to bisect the graph recursively by calculating the fiedler vector of the Laplacian matrix so that at each step the number of connections lost is minimum. However, after bisecting the graph, the sequence of displaying the bisections of these two graphs could also increase the number of connections displayed. Thus this method is not very satisfactory to me.

My question is whether we could sort the nodes in increasing order of the fiedler vector and display them in the same order in the grid? Are there other easy and intuitive grid layout algorithms for graphs?